# How to tell which radio button value is selected in my MVC controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, radio-button

I have two radio buttons on my asp.net MVC 3 View, and I want to know which one is selected inside my controller. Can someone please propose the solution?

```
<input value="offline" type="radio" name="rdoOnline" />  Offline Billing

<input value="online" type="radio" name="rdoOnline" /> Online Billing
```

Answer (score 1):

I used jQuery for this example, but simple HtmlForm may be used too.

In controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeResult(string SelectedValue)
{
   var result = SelectedValue
return View();
}
```

In View:

```
<script>
$('.button').click(function(){

$post('/Home/SomeResult?'+ $('input[name=office]:checked').val())

});

<script>


<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="office" value="true" checked="checked"><label for="radio1">Yes</label>
<input id="radio2"" type="radio" name="office" value="false"><label for="radio2">No</label>

<button class="button">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you might wanna add `value` to your `<input>` so that you are able to choose which one got selected.

```
<input type="radio" name="rdoOnline" value="option1"/> 
<input type="radio" name="rdoOnline" value="option2"/>
```

You can then select base on the value and process accordingly.

Comment: May be View Model with a Boolean Property ?

Comment: Frankly i'm not really clear. But i'm sure that the radio input type is able to give a true or false when selected through http post or get method

Answer (score 0):

Add value attribute to both radio button.

//in view

```
<input type="radio" name="rdoOnline" value="online1"/> 
<input type="radio" name="rdoOnline" value="online2"/>
```

//in controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourFunction(FormCollection fc)
{
   if(fc["rdoOnline"] != null)
       string radiovalue=Convert.ToString(fc["rdoOnline"]);
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: May be View Model with a Boolean Property ?

Comment: No, it will give you selected value, not true or false. In this case Online1 or online2.